# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type queue in C

Tags: c, pointers, null, queue, void

I want to make a queue using nodes, since it will be empty upon creation i want head and tail to point to NULL. But when i try to do it i get the error in the title. Any ideas?

```
 typedef struct node node_t;
 typedef struct queue queue_t;


 struct node{
        void *info;
        struct node *next;
 };

 struct queue{
        node_t *head;
        node_t *tail;
 };

queue_t* new_queue(void){
        queue_t* q = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
        if (q == NULL)
                return NULL;
        q->tail = NULL;
        q->head = NULL;
        return q;
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the error i get when i try to compile this:

(gcc queue.c -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -g -o q)

unt.c: In function ‘new_queue’:

unt.c:30:31: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘queue_t’

queue_t* q = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));

```
                           ^
```

unt.c:33:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

q->tail = NULL;
      ^

unt.c:34:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

q->head = NULL;
      ^

unt.c:35:2: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

return q;
  ^

Comment: Do you have the definitions of `struct queue` in another file that you forgot to include? That error occurs when the compiler doesn't know the contents of a struct, i.e. which fields and what size it has.

Comment: I made a new file with the content of the post and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it compiles just fine. try to move the typedefs below the struct declaration

```
 struct node{
    void *info;
    struct node *next;
  };

 struct queue{
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
 };

 typedef struct node node_t;
 typedef struct queue queue_t;
```

other than that it seems ok

EDIT:
also the stdlib and stdio includes should be cheked.

Comment: The code compiles correctly with typedefs at the top.

Comment: i know, actually i have tried it before posting but for some reason i remembered that it could cause a problem so i wrote it

Comment: Anton the error i got is in the post when i try to compile it.

Comment: which includes you have in the file?

Comment: I forgot about them hahaha now i added: stdio.h stdbool.h and stdlib.h. The error is updated. Sorry about that :P

Comment: @Bluuu did it fix that problem?

Comment: The new error i got is shorter but it still says something about the dereferencing pointer :/

Comment: Just realized the error!!! I had an extra _ in the original code!! Thanks anton for taking time to answer.